# I need to hide my FloatingActionButton when scrolling a SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter

I need to hide my FloatingActionButton when scrolling a SingleChildScrollView. I found something about how to hide it when the user scrolls down and then show it when the user scrolls up, but that's not what I'm looking for.
I want the button to remain hidden only during the scroll. I also tried playing with the NotificationListener but didn't come up with a solution

Answer (score 0):

Hide until you don't get any more notifications.

```
NotificationListener<UserScrollNotification>(
  onNotification: (notification) {
    if (_show) setState(() => _show = false);
    _timer?.cancel();
    _timer = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 200), () => setState(() => _show = true));
    return true;
  },
  child: <your widget>
)
```

Comment: I've tried this too, but it's not smooth and often repeats the animation twice. I was looking for a better way, but thanks

Comment: I think this happens because if the slide is continuous, no notification arrives even though it is still scrolling